# How to upgrade Cordova on Sencha Touch 2

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've been developing an iOS app with Sencha Touch 2.3 with Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.6.

Now the Cordova 3.6 is out, I would like to upgrade the Cordova of my application to the latest version. I can't seem to find any documentation on the matter.

It looks like following commands will do the trick:

```
sencha cordova remove

# Upgrade to the new Cordova version

sencha cordova init
```

Has anyone done this? Are there any pitfalls in doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You should go into the cordova folder and upgrade cordova from there

```
cd cordova

cordova upgrade
```